# Does the "Far Out Man" Talent affect Basic Attacks in Divinity: Original Sin 2?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

In the Talent menu, **Far Out Man** states that it affects both Spells and Skills (as opposed to just spells in 1,) but not Melee or Touch-Range skills. Does the "Basic Attack" hotbar item count as a Skill for ranged weapons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the wiki, [it does affect ranged weapon range](http://divinityoriginalsin2.wiki.fextralife.com/Far+Out+Man):

> ## Tips
>
> - Also applies to ranged basic attacks.

And from the comment section:

> This talent also works for ranged weapon attacks (bows).